# rs232 / I receive only commands I sent before

Tags: serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with an old roboter via rs232, but I'm receiving only the string I sent before. Baudrate seems to be correct.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are sending, and what you are receiving, and what the roboter context is?

Comment: It's a very old robot without brand name or label. I found some notices, which the command "0h31" should send back the serial number. But I recive always the command I sent. I tried also sending carriage return and linefeed at the end of the command, but also got just an echo. Could it be Rx TX switch problem?